# how can I obtain grails hibernate L2 cache statistics?

Tags: hibernate, grails, profiling, ehcache

grails hibernate L2 cache statistics - net.sf.ehcache.Statistics

I am using ehcache with my L2 cache.

I want to profile the performance and obtain statistics from net.sf.ehcache.Statistics.
Without any success, I have been searching for a way to access the L2 cache manager from Grails or Spring.

I appreciated any hint.

Bellow are typical hibernate settings used

```
hibernate {

    cache.use_second_level_cache = true

    cache.use_query_cache = true

    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'

    format_sql = true

    use_sql_comments = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get hold of the `sessionFactory` by having it injected into your service and then [enable statistics](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html) on it:

```
class My Service {

  def sessionFactory

  def myMethod() {
    // Enable stats
    Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
    stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

   // Do some querying and analyse the stats

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed that “stats.getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames()” is only returning “StandardQueryCache, UpdateTimestampsCache”.

Am I looking into the correct place to verify my L2 cache?

Bellow is my domain class mapping.

    class LogCauseMemento {
 
       static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned'
        table 'log_cause'
        cache: true
        }
    }

Bellow is the domain entry ehcache.xml.

    <cache name="com.att.failbox.log.cause.LogCauseMemento"
             maxElementsInMemory="100000"
           eternal="true"
  />

Comment: The Hibernate documentation is good on this (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache). You can call `sessionFactory.getStatistics()
        .getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(regionName)
        .getEntries();` where the `regionName` cane be found by calling `getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `generate_statistics=true` to your Hibernate settings:

```
hibernate {
    ...
    generate_statistics=true
    ...
}
```